# Vuetify carousel looping

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify carousel - I cannot find the way to turn off the looping. I do not show images in my vuetify carousel, I use for a few steps for the user -passive steps, more like a description step by step and I don't need the loop in the carousel..

Thanks for help

[EDIT]
For those who are interested I ended up using vue-carousel

Comment: Hi Yanatrtr, welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for anyone to help out, please consider added code to your question before posting. With so little information we are not able to help. Here are some tips on [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There is now a `continuous` (default=true) prop now.

You can turn it off by setting it like so: `:continuous="false"`

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. Almost began writing some weird slot logic

Answer (score 0):

THe docs of Vuetify do not provide any info of such option.
But...

Since you do not use it as carousel but as stepper, why don't you use stepper..?
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers

[EDIT]

Either I was blind yesterday or it just appeared - the docs mention now the `cycle` prop of carousel: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels#api
I think you should give it a try by setting this to `false`. ;)

Comment: Thanks but I need the slider of the carousel.. The user suppose to slide the steps till the last step

Comment: @yanatrtr please check this answer again, seems I missed one prop of the carousel or it just appeared in the docs.

Comment: cycle prop is for automatic cycling(true) or canceling the auromatic cycling(false).. I've checked this before posting the question.. thanks for you help

Comment: Well, there is nothing to thank for then... Since vuetify is still under active development I'd suggest reporting such feature request on their GitHub.